# How to get the file name given in tkinter save dialog

Tags: python

I am new to python. I use tkinter to create a text file editor. I try to save the file contents to a text file. If i save the file name as "abc.txt" or "abc", how do i get the file name in code which is given in file name dialog before saving the file. Thanks in advance!

[image]

**Code:**

```
def save_file():
    files = [('Text Document','*.txt'), ('Python Files','*.py')]
    wfile = asksaveasfilename(filetypes = files, defaultextension=".txt")
    filename = wfile.get() <==== this line is not correct and throws an error
    wrfile = open(filename,"w")
    wrfile.write(str(txt.get(1.0, END)))
    wrfile.close()
```

Comment: `wfile` is already a string with the file name. `tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()` returns a string.

Comment: Yes, so how can i get the file name in code either before or after saving the file?

Comment: from your code, just remove `filename = wfile.get()` and replace the other references to `filename` with `wfile`? If you want to retain that file name after, just return the string at the end of the function. Otherwise, I don't understand what you mean by "file name in code either before or after saving the file".

Comment: Once i click on save button, the file name should be get into a variable. I hope, the file name cannot be get before clicking on save button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

code:

```
def save_file():
    files = [('Text Document','*.txt'), ('Python Files','*.py')]
    wfile = asksaveasfile(filetypes = files, defaultextension=".txt")
    filename = wfile  
    print(wfile)
```

Comment: did you mean to leave the `this line is not correct and throws an error` comment in there?

Comment: not disputing that it will function, just checking if the commented out section was intended to be kept or just a leftover from the original post.

Comment: I remove it. Thanks